# Proguard and 3rd party libraries

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

I have runnable jar with couple of 3rd party jars inside it. Do I have to specify those libraries with Proguard's -libraryjar option even if they are already packed in the main jar file?

At the moment I'm these errors:

```
Warning: there were 171 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning: there were 394 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
```

If I specify the jars with -libraryjar option Proguard warns alot about duplicate classes.

My ant build:

```
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <delete file="${destfile}" />
    <jar destfile="${destfile}" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain" duplicate="preserve">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="main.Main"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${classpath}"/>
        </manifest>
    <fileset dir="${target}" includes="**/*.class" />
        <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="lib1.jar" />
        <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="lib2.jar" />
        <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="lib3.jar" />
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="dist" depends="jar">
    <taskdef resource="proguard/ant/task.properties" classpath="${proguard}" />
    <proguard>
        -injars      ${destfile}
        -outjars     ${destfileobfuscated}
        -libraryjars C:/Java/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/lib/rt.jar;
                     C:/Java/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/lib/jsse.jar;
                     C:/Java/jdk1.6.0_25/jre/lib/jce.jar;
                     lib1.jar;
                     lib2.jar;
                     lib3.jar

        -optimizationpasses 5
        -overloadaggressively
        -repackageclasses ''
        -allowaccessmodification
        -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers

        -keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
            public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
        }
    </proguard>
    <move file="${destfileobfuscated}" tofile="${destfile}" />
</target>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `proguard` you must assign your 3rd party library jars with the following command:

```
-libraryjars  jar1.jar, jar2.jar, jar3.jar...
```

If you don't include these jars as above, the code related to them will not be obfuscated/optimized/shrinked because they will be unresolved with respect to `proguard`.

It's OK if it warns, because it will find a lot of classes with the same name, it's normal, but this wont have any negative impacts on the outcome.

Comment: I have updated my question, can you please check the ant build if it looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used proguard, but I've used yguard and the concept is the same.

If the .class file are already in the jar being processed then there's no need to add them again. The error about unresolved classes may be due to some of the code that you don't use depending on classes that are not available. If the code is never called this isn't a problem. The best thing to do is to try and run the application and see what classes are not available, then add those. I wouldn't rely on the output of proguard to determine if all the required code is available.

You don't have jar files inside the jar file, right? That won't work.